# how to pass session value from mvc controller to asp page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session

I am trying to pass the session from mvc controller to asp page

```
public ActionResult RedretToMyAspPage()
{
    var result = MySerive.GetData(stuData);
     Session["stuDataCode"] = stuData;
    if (result.Result)
    {
        Response.Redirect(result.redirectToURL);
    }
    return View();
}
```

and on asp page am getting session by

```
dim studata
dim len
len = Len( Session( "stuDataCode" ))
studata = Session( "stuDataCode" )
```

but here I am getting len = 0

Comment: Are `dim` and `Len` exist in C#? This doesn't look like C# code.

Comment: @mmushtaq, nope .. that's legacy VB code

Comment: that is the problem i have to pass session from mvc to asp page

Answer (score 1):

**No**, you can't access the `session` this way cause both your application (MVC and ASP.NET) probably running on different application pool with different `w3wp` worker process. Thus the session won't be available. One solution is to use `pooled session` (or) use client side mechanism `cookie` (or) pass it to the URL as a query string parameter, e.g. `localhost:1234/foo?stuDataCode=1234`